# how does a button_to in rails request a JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im a rails noob, so bear with me.

I have the following in new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New page</h1>

<%= render 'pages/form' %>

<% if @page != 1 %>
<%= button_to 'New Page', pages_path %>
<%= button_to 'Done!', :action=> 'generate' %>

<% end %>
```

my controller looks like this

```
def generate
@presentation = current_presentation
respond_to do |format|
format.json { render json: @presentation.pages}
format.html {render :text => "html"}
end
```

end

I want the response to be JSON, but the code goes to format.html.

How do I instruct the button_to that my requested response is JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if just one of them or both, but try `:remote => true` and `data-type`:

```
<%= button_to "Create", :action => "create", :remote => true, :form => { "data-type" => "json" } %>
```

Comment: Thanks - I have already tried that, but no cigar. Just is format.html

Comment: You might be missing `respond_to :html, :json` on your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Using a path helper to build the path worked for me.  eg.

```
<%= button_to "Create Widgit", widgits_path(format: 'json'), remote: true %>
```